# Python: Get indices of common values in 3 sorted arrays

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, unique

I have three sorted arrays:

```
>>> a = arange(10)
>>> b = arange(3,12)
>>> c = arange(-2,8)
>>> print(a)
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
>>> print(b)
[ 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
>>> print(c)
[-2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7]
```

I want to get a list of the indices of the elements of each array that are contained in all of the other arrays as well.

In this example, it would be the indices in each array that correspond to the numbers 3 - 7

so something like:

```
a_inds, b_inds, c_inds = get_unq_inds(a,b,c)

a_inds = [3,4,5,6,7] (or [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  False,  False])

b_inds = [0,1,2,3,4] (or [True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False])
```

etc

Basically, I want to expand the solution provided here:
([Find indices of common values in two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32653441/find-indices-of-common-values-in-two-arrays))
to 3 arrays. (Or, if you're feeling ambitious, 'n' arrays)

Comment: So do you want a list of indices or a list of booleans?

Comment: I think either one would serve my purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
def get_unq_inds(a, b, c):
    uniq_vals = list(set(a).intersection(b).intersection(c))
    return [a.index(x) for x in uniq_vals], [b.index(x) for x in uniq_vals], [c.index(x) for x in uniq_vals]
    # you can use this for boolean values
    #return [x in uniq_vals for x in a], [x in uniq_vals for x in b], [x in uniq_vals for x in c]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
a_inds, b_inds, c_inds = get_unq_inds(range(9), range(3,12), range(-2,8))

>>> a_inds, b_inds, c_inds
([3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

**OUTPUT** for boolean values :

```
[False, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, False]
[True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, True]
```

Live demo [here](https://repl.it/NaXo/2)

Comment: yeh +1 our combined answers seem best if the order is not important

Comment: Actually I’m no longer convinced this is best because the index calls add time complexity, still a neat idea though

Answer (score 1):

For a list of booleans, you can use a list comprehension.

```
a_inds = [x in b and x in c for x in a]
```

Comment: I think this should be [x in b AND x in c  for x in a]? But I love the simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine all your ranges to get the common elements in a `set` and then test against this:

```
>>> ranges = [range(9), range(3,12), range(-2,8)]
>>> s = set.intersection(*map(set,ranges))
>>> [[i for i,x in enumerate(sublist) if x in s] for sublist in ranges]
[[3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

This will work for any number of input lists.

Or similarly using the same `s` with @Ashish Ranjan's idea (note the indices may not be ordered though because we are iterating over the unordered `set()`, although in practise they are likely to maintain the order due to the way Python hash's integers):

```
[[sublist.index(x) for x in s] for sublist in ranges]
```